# Privilege Escalation (Linux / Windows)

Tags: linux

I Want Some Books or somethin about windows / linux privilege escalation, enumeration.. tips etc i know the basic.. enumeration os version / kernel version etc

Answer (score 1):

These are very good starting points

## Linux

- [Gotm1lk's basic privilege escalation guide](https://blog.g0tmi1k.com/2011/08/basic-linux-privilege-escalation/)
- [Kernel exploits](https://github.com/lucyoa/kernel-exploits)
- `searchsploit linux/local` (can slim down results: `searchsploit kernel linux/local`
- [VulnHub](https://www.vulnhub.com/)

---

## Windows

- `searchsploit windows/local`, `searchsploit win_x86/local` (can slim down results: `searchsploit Microsoft Windows VERSION local`, etc.
- [Fuzzy Security guide](http://www.fuzzysecurity.com/tutorials/16.html)

## Both

- www.google.com
- Learning how to use the operating system(s) in question.

Comment: i have solve a lot of.. CTF machines.. but i want to have a list of privilege escalation.. and.. why in searchsploit u add local ?

Comment: I'm adding local because you seem like you just want to practice privilege escalation, right? And you already have shell access, correct? So 99.9% of those are "local" exploits. It may be a local buffer overflow, escalation, race condition, whatever. If you already have a shell, and need to escalate, then all will be categorized under local.

Comment: yep true.. i have read books about penetration testing.. ethical haking but noone explain privilege escalation.. say very basic things.. UAC bypass etc.. do you have something for windows / linux enumeration ?

Comment: If you understand the purpose of all the commands in the two guides I linked, you will have very little trouble with privilege escalation, provided the machine is exploitable. All of the information I provided is all you need to really get started. It's up to you to put in the effort.

Comment: Good Thank You and something else.. do you know good CTF based on privilege escalation.. i need to practise on this.. i download systems from vulnhub but this systems have very basic exploitation.. (not all)